# Excel VBA: Increment a Row Before Printing

Tags: events, vba, excel

I am completely new to Excel VBA scripts. Is there some way to increment a certain cell - e.g. cell 7D - each time there is a `print` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to read about the Workbook.BeforePrint event. This is covered in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.beforeprint%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). However you'd need to be careful about what happens if you click "Print" but then cancel the print dialog, if you are trying to count the number of times the document has been printed for example.